# How Find mysql database which have most query?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible find most frequently mysql database or query that run in mysql server whiteout enable mysql general logging ?
in short term i want know which mysql database or query most repeat in mysql server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see what sql queries are running currently by using

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

If you want to look at it historically, you will need to log it somehow.

Comment: that above command show query now running , I need historical data.